# Is it possible to use commands like `fg` in a shell-script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, job-control, jobs

I am trying to create a fun Terminal Screensaver which consists of the `cmatrix` package (one that turns terminal in one similar to the movie **The Matrix**) and `xprintidle` to determine idle time of the Terminal.

I took some help from this [Thread answer at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/638357/execute-a-command-if-linux-is-idle-for-5-minutes#638487) and using a shell-script similar to it as follows:

#### screensaver.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x  # Used for debugging
IDLE_TIME=$((60*1000)) #a minute in milliseconds

screen_saver(){
# My screensaver function
    cmatrix -abs
}

sleep_time=$IDLE_TIME
triggered=false

while sleep $(((sleep_time+999)/1000)); do
    idle=$(xprintidle)
    if [ $idle -ge $IDLE_TIME ]; then
        if ! $triggered; then
            screen_saver
            triggered=true
            sleep_time=$IDLE_TIME
        fi
    else
        triggered=false
        sleep_time=$((IDLE_TIME -idle+100))
    fi
done
```

The script runs flawlessly when I run it in foreground using:

```
./screensaver.sh
```

and I can see the matrix terminal triggered.

However If I run it in background with `&`; the function `screen_saver()` is triggered in the background and I cannot view it. The only possible way to see the matrix terminal is using `fg` which brings it foreground.

### Question

Is it possible to use the `fg` command in the function `screen_saver()` like:

```
screen_saver(){
     cmatrix -abs && fg
}
```

or similar option to bring it to the foreground within the shell-script?

I wish to add this script into my `.bashrc` so that it actually becomes a customizable feature. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably not, according to: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/can-a-process-bring-itself-back-to-the-foreground-on-completion-aix-ksh

Comment: While you can't use `fg` the way you mean, this shouldn't prevent you from seeing the output of `cmatrix`. Can you reproduce the problem with a small script that doesn't use `cmatrix`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fg` job commands are connected to interactive sessions only, and have no meaning in batch mode (scripts).

Technically, you could enable them with `set -m`, but it still would make little (if any) sense, as this only relates to interactive applications where you can send jobs to back by ^Z, but since you don't have that interaction in a shell script, it makes it pointless.

The answer is: in practice, No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

If you use tmux it has a option for "screensaver"

```
set -g lock-command "cmatrix -abs"
set -g lock-after-time 10 #inSeconds
```

Not exactly a answer to your question.

Comment: Will give this a try. Kudos for `tmux`